# Can pointer of specific type be assigned to pointer to union which contains the same type as one of it's members?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, c99, unions

Let's say I have following piece of code, defining a structure and a union:

```c
struct Foo
{
    int i;
    float f;
};


union Bar
{
    struct Foo foo;
    char buf[10];
};
```

Is it safe to assign pointer to object of type `struct Foo` in place of pointer to type `union Bar` and subsequently use it as such:

```c
struct Foo fooVar;

union Bar* barPtrVar = (union Bar*) &fooVar;

bar->foo.i = 1000;
bar->foo.f = 0.5f;
```

as long as we are sure that only the `foo` member of the `union Bar` is used?

I remember that in C, pointer to the struct is the same as pointer to it's first member and as such they can be sometimes interchangeable, so though similar logic might apply here.

Comment: I would tend to guess that `Bar* barPtrVar = (Bar*)&fooVar` is safe.

Comment: What is pointer `bar`? Is it supposed to be `barPtrVar`?

Comment: Re “pointer to the struct is the same as pointer to it's first member”: Not the same as, but one can be converted to the other; converting a pointer to a structure to a pointer to the type of its first member yields a pointer to its first member and vice-versa, and the same holds for a union with any of its members. But that does not apply here because your code does not create a `union Bar` and convert a pointer to it or its first member to another type. It creates a stand-alone `struct Foo` that is not part of a union. So that is not the conversion you are making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is not safe. A union type will have an alignment size at least as large as the maximum alignment size of its members. Thus, a `union Bar` containing a member of type `struct Foo` could have stricter alignment than a `struct Foo`.  (This is unlikely in OP's example since the other member of `union Bar` has an alignment size of 1, but it is true in general.)

Consider the code sequence:

```
struct Foo fooVar;

union Bar* barPtrVar = (union Bar*) &fooVar;
```

If `union Bar` has stricter alignment than `struct Foo`, then this conversion will result in *undefined behavior*, as per [C11 6.3.2.3/7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7) (emphasis mine):

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. **If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned<sup>68)</sup> for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.** Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

The expression `barPtrVar->foo` (of type `struct Foo`) is problematic because the identifier following the `->` designates a member of a structure or union object, but `barPtrVar` is not actually pointing to a `union Bar` so `barPtrVar->foo` is not actually a member of a structure or union object, as per  [C11 6.5.2.3/4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.3p4) (emphasis mine):

> A postfix expression followed by the **`->`** operator and an identifier **designates a member of a structure or union object**. The value is that of the named member of the object to which the first expression points, and is an lvalue.<sup>96)</sup> If the first expression is a pointer to a qualified type, the result has the so-qualified version of the type of the designated member.

Additionally, storing a value in `barPtrVar->foo` (of type `struct Foo`) may also modify bytes of the `union Bar` that are not part of the `foo` member, as per [C11 6.2.6.1/7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.1p7):

> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.

Since `barPtrVar` is not pointing to a `union Bar`, but is pointing to a smaller `struct Foo`, bytes *outside the bounds* of the supposed member `foo` (of type `struct Foo`) may take unspecified values, resulting in undefined behavior because those bytes are not actually part of a `union Bar`.

Answer (score 3):

This usage is safe, even if you read from the `buf` member (up to a point).

Section 6.5p7 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) gives the following aliasing rules:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - **an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>   subaggregate or contained union), or**
> - **a character type.**

Your use case falls under the second-to-last bullet point, and reading from the `buf` member *up to `buf[sizeof(struct Foo)-1]`* is allowed as per the last bullet point.

Comment: *How* would you use `buf`? The `struct Foo fooVar;` being pointed to isn't even large enough to contain it.

Comment: As for the `buf` member, I guess it's only safe as long as I read from index that does not go outside `sizeof(struct Foo)` (so `bar->foo.buf[7]` is safe but `bar->foo.buf[9]` is not), do I surmise correctly?

Comment: @NeutralEffect Correct, I've updated to include that detail.

Comment: I don't think this can be the intended meaning of the second-to-last bullet point. Consider C17 6.2.6.1p7. Storing to `bar->foo` could also modify parts of `bar->buf` that are not part of `bar->foo`, including the parts of `bar->buf` outside the bounds of `fooVar`.

Comment: Also `union Bar` may have stricter alignment than `struct Foo`, so accessing a `struct Foo` through a `union Bar *` may not be correctly aligned (I mean in general, not in this specific case where the other member of `union Bar` has an alignment size of 1).